# метод для закрывания модуля при нажатии вне блока

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Есть два модуля, у них есть общая функция `clickaway`, которая срабатывает по клику вне блока, при нажатии на кнопку `.btn_menu` модуль `submenu` закрывается, но вот при нажатии на `.btn_submenu` уже где-то затирается эвент.
Где-то нужно удалить / восстановить эвент? подскажите пожалуйтса)

```js
var menu = (function() {
  var opened = false,
    $btn = $('.btn_menu');
  //events
   $btn.click(toggle)
   clickAway($btn, function() {
     console.log('click away close menu')
   })

  function toggle() {
    if (!opened) {
      console.log('menu opened')
    } else {
      console.log('menu closed')
    }
    opened = !opened
  }
})();

var submenu = (function() {
  var opened = false,
    $btn = $('.btn_submenu');
    //events
    $btn.click(toggle);
    clickAway($btn, function() {
     console.log('click away close submenu')
   })
  
  function toggle() {
    if (!opened) {
      console.log('submenu opened')
    } else {
      console.log('submenu closed')
    }
    opened = !opened
    return false
  }
})();

function clickAway(selector, cb) {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(selector).is(e.target) && !$(e.target).closest(selector).length) {
      cb()
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.btn {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn_menu">menu</button>
<button class="btn btn_submenu">submenu</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в функциях `toggle` несимметричный.

Возвращение `false` из обработчика `click` jQuery равнозначно вызовам `e.preventDefault();` и `e.stopPropagation();`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

```
  function toggle(e) {
    if (!opened) {
      console.log('submenu opened')
    } else {
      console.log('submenu closed')
    }
    opened = !opened
    //!!! return false
  }
```